# How to upload Images in codeigniter with mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

Note is that : All data is inserted properly. 
               But if i'm upload an image with the help of 
               $this->upload->do_upload();and validate id,
               this is not properly working. can u suggest..

```
//Controller

public function saveEmployeea()
    {

      $config = [ 'upload_path'=>'./uploads',
          'allowed_types'=>'gif|jpg|png|jpeg'];

      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('dept_name', 'Department', 'required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('middlename', 'Middle Name','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('gendar', 'Gendar','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('address1', 'Local Address','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('address2', 'Permant Address','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('nationality', 'Nationality','required');


      $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_of_joining', 'Joinig Date','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('current_designation', 'Designation_Curnt','required');

      // $this->form_validation->set_rules('profile_image', 'Please Upload image','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('prof_email_id', 'Professional Email Id','required|valid_email');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('personal_email', 'Personal Email Id','required|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('personal_no', 'Personal Contact No','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('emergency_no', 'Emergency No','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('highest_qualification', 'Highest Qualificatio','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('year_of_passing', 'Year Of Passing','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('university', 'University','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_experience', 'No Experience','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('pre_compony', 'Previus Compony','required');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('pre_designation', 'Previus Designation','required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('pre_organisation_location', 'Previus organisation_location','required');




      if ( $this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload()) 
      {

        $data = $this->input->post();


        // insert images in data variables by using upload object oprater.
        $upload_info = $this->upload->data();



        //set path for images store 
        $path = base_url("uploads/".$upload_info['raw_name'].$upload_info['file_ext']);

        $data['profile_image'] = $path;

        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($data);
        // echo '</pre>';
        // var_dump($data);
        // exit();  

        // Load Model to Call Model class
        $this->load->model('Loginm');


        if($this->Loginm->insertEmployee($data))
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('employee_details','Employee Details Added Successfully');
        }   
        else
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('employee_details','Failed To Added Employee Details.');
        }
          return redirect('Employee/EmployeeList'); 

      }
      else
      {
        $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->createEmployee();
      }
    }


// Model

public function insertEmployee($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('employee',$data);
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
     $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')
```

here 'userfile' in the name attribute in the input element.

```
     <form action="url" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input type="file" name="userfile" accept="image/*">
```

make sure you use: 
enctype="multipart/form-data" 
or 
CI 3 counterpart: 
echo form_open_multipart();

second,

The Upload Directory

You’ll need a destination directory for your uploaded images. Create a directory at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and set its file permissions to 777.

you may have file permission issue in the upload directory that you set. You should set proper permissions to the upload directory.

References:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: thanks for responce ..but im already laod in library, creating config, and pass this config to upload object.

Comment: use the name field... $this->upload->do_upload('userfile') and check  whether you have echoed form_open_multipart()

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$config['upload_path']    = 'd:/www/project_name/uploads/'; //document root path
$config['allowed_types']  = 'jpg|gif|png';
$config['file_name']      = $_FILES['profile_image']['name'];

//load upload class library
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('profile_image'))
{
        // case - failure
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
}
else
{
    // case - SUCCESS
}
```